# How MFC CComboBox data item stored?

Tags: mfc

In MFC, (Visual Studio -> design mode -> resource view), CCombobox has 'data' property. This property is for populating data items in combo box. But when dialog.rc (resource) file is opened in notepad, it doesn't contain the same data items. My question is how these combo box items are stored if they don't exist in dialog box resource (dialog.rc) file ?

Comment: I hardly ever use the VS 'visual' resource editor these days but, when I used to, there was always a ***big*** file created with the (IIRC) .aps extension. VS2019 has moved all its temp stuffs to a separate folder, but the data are probably in there, somewhere.

Comment: The .aps file is always just temporary and keeps no interesting data.

Answer (score 0):

I found:
Data is being stored into same resource file but in other section in some HEX codes.

Comment: MIght be worth adding that it's held in a DLGINIT resource.